# Changing a hotkey

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shortcut

I'd like to make the hotkey "alt-z" switch me into Material shading mode instead of Textured. However, there's no "change/add shortcut" option on these buttons.

Would somebody please let me know how to do this?

Comment: Alt+Z can be searched just fine by [key-binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql4tJ.jpg), there change the mode you want to enter. How did you search the setting then? Or use UI Pie Menu addon and use Tab for all the modes

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks, I was unfamiliar with that part of the User Preferences. Normally I just right-click on an option to change the hotkey. I can select this as the accepted answer if you post it as such. :-)

Comment: @MrZak, you should add your answer as an answer instead of in the comments so that this question can be marked as solved.

Comment: @rioforce you or anyone else are welcome to add the answer instead, I'm not going to, elaborate only a bit on what to do, steps, screenshots etc.